# Why should we integrate to find displacement instead of directly plugging in $t$ for displacement function?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, calculus, displacement

context:preparing for jee, chapter kinematics. text book problem 
given $v = 2t^2$ 
find $x$ at $t=2s$ if at $t = 1s$, $x= 3m$

### My solution

integrating v to find displacement fucntion
$$
x(t) = \int2t^2dt = \frac{2}{3}t^3
$$
plugging in $t=2s$ 
 $x(2) = 5.3333m$

### Text book solution

$$
v = \frac{dx}{dt}
$$
$$
dx = vdt
$$
integrating on both sides
$$
\int dx = \int vdt
$$
taking limits correspondingly
$$
\int_3^x dx = \int_1^2 2t^2dt
$$
solving for x
$$
x-3 = \frac{2}{3}(7)
$$

$$
x = \frac{23}{3} = 7.666m
$$

**The question is why did we integrated and took limits to find answer and why is direct substitution wrong? can someone explain *why*? isnt integrating velocity gives displacement function and plugging in time will give us displacement then why is this method wrong?**

Comment: Remember that the primitive of a function is not unique... Your solution implicitly sets the constant to 0. That's why it does not hold that at t=1, x=3, as required.

Comment: Think of it this way, without setting the limits of integration the way they are, you are not taking the object from its designated initial point to its final point. you cant assume particle is at origin of your reference frame as the only piece of data given is x=3 at t=1, you build your answer off of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution, the $x=3$ at $t=1$ condition is violated (check your formula). To fix that, remember that $x(t)=\int 2t^2dt=\frac{2}{3}t^3+C$. Use the $x=3$ at $t=1$ condition to find $C$, then proceed with plugging in $t=2$.